# Remove Itemid from URL generated from manual links in articles

Tags: joomla-3.x, url, joomla-3.9, weblinks

I have been looking for hours but I have been unable to find an answer for my case.

I have an *Article* which is used for the *home* menu. For some reason the *Read More* option is not working but that is for another question. What I did, was added a simple link to a new *Article* with the full information.
The problem I am having, is that I am just using `index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=136` as the URL but then on the site it always appends the `Itemid` for the menu (`index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=136&Itemid=435`) thus causing my site to display all the content in the home page when I only need to display the article and nothing more.

Is there an option or a parameter that does this? I had resorted to using .httaccess with an ugly rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)&Itemid=[0-9a-z]+$|^Itemid=[0-9a-z]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteBase /Nuevo
RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1 [R=301,L]
```

Which causes different problems.

Any help would mean a lot.

Comment: Welcome Elder.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for feedback/support.  We always appreciate questions that include some form of an attempt to resolve the issue (successful or not). Good job on your first question.

Comment: Is SEF enabled?

Comment: SEF is not enabled, but even if enabled the error persist. I would rather have a fix without using SEF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla needs to have an indication of the menuitem (ie itemid) to know how to display all the stuff around the item being shown - templates, modules etc. It tries to determine the most appropriate menuitem to use based on certain things like what menuitem you're currently on, language etc. It looks as if Joomla is using the itemid of your home page.

I suggest you try setting up a separate menuitem which simply displays an article - shown the way you'd like to have it. Then pass the itemid of that menuitem in your URL. If you set the menuitem to hidden then it won't be displayed in any menu - ie it won't be visible to users.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what was happening. I created new menu items for the links within the site to the single articles and it does what I wanted now.